# Spring @Value is always null

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring in my app and I have a .properties file which has some values defined.

In a java class there is a String value:

```
@Value("${test}")
public String value;
```

The point is that if I inject this value in beans definition:

```
<bean id="customClass" class="package.customClass.CustomClassImpl">
    <property name="value" value="${test}"></property>
</bean>
```

It works fine, but if I use `@Value`, there is always a `null`... Why is that happening?

And no, I'm not doing any "`new`" no instantiate "`customClass`", I get it with `context.getBean("customClass)`.

**EDIT:** I have configured a property placeholder in the context:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:constants.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Property in xml example is named like ‘test’ in annotation you are using name ‘value’ please double check property names.

Comment: Edited, it was a little mistake, in my source code it's okey

Comment: show us the customClass code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve, you need to enable annotation config in configuration file: `<context:annotation-config/>`

Answer (score 8):

Remember, your class need a stereotype annotation like `@Component` or `@Service`

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating spring boot application and your goal is to provide configuration parameter(s) via (application).properties there is a way to do it without explicit @Value declaration.

Create YourClassProperties with annotation @ConfigurationProperties("some.prefix"):

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my.example")
public class MyClassProperties {
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Add defined properties to (application).properties:

```
my.example.foo=bar
```

And then, in your application you can autowire needed properties...

```
@Autowired
private MyClassProperties myClassProperties;
```

... and use them as you would any other properties:

```
LOG.info("Value of the foo: {}", myClassProperties.getFoo());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your .properties file using @PropertySource. Not sure it's doable using xml config.

Also, are you sure about this "$", it's "#" in this example :
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/61645-value-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer